# Why does MySQL stored proc converting in X datetime to NAME_CONST?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-python

Should I be concerned that when I run "show processlist" mysql is using NAME_CONST() for my passed in datetime parameter?

For example:

```
create procedure sp_test(IN startdate DATETIME, IN enddate DATETIME)
BEGIN
    select * from my_table a
    where a.visit_date between startdate and enddate;
END
```

I call this in either python:

```
cursor.callproc('sp_test', ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 23:59:59'])
```

Or in my sql client of choice:

```
call sp_test('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 23:59:59');
```

When I view "show processlist", I get this (formatted a bit for readability):

```
select * from my_table a
where a.visit_date between 
NAME_CONST('startdate',_latin1'2018-01-01 00:00:00' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci') 
and NAME_CONST('enddate',_latin1'2018-01-01 23:59:59' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci')
```

I'm curious if this is correct? Am I passing in datetime wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, everything is correct. This is just an internal conversion by MySQL.

Read more about the function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_name-const)

Some extracts from provided link:

> Returns the given value. When used to produce a result set column, NAME_CONST() causes the column to have the given name.
>
> **This function is for internal use only.** The server uses it when writing statements from stored programs that contain references to local program variables

Comment: Thank you for the response. That has cleared this up!

Comment: @datacubed Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking the check left to my answer :)